# assign column alias to where condition not work in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Today I faced a problem, that below sql query is not working in sqlite but works in mysql.

It has the same table structure both in mysql and sqlite

```
Table structure
========================

tablet_order |  framework_item_id | framework_parent_id

1            |           1        |            0

2            |           2        |            1

3            |           3        |            2
```

SQL:

```
SELECT tablet_order AS tablet, (

SELECT framework_item_id
FROM framework
WHERE tablet_order = tablet
) AS tablet1
FROM framework
WHERE framework_item_id =1
```

The alias 'tablet' is assigned to tablet_order field. This made an error in sqlite but not in mysql.

Anybody can u explain this....

Comment: What's wrong with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5de5f/6/0 ( I guess I don't see the point of the inner select at this time)  worse if tablet_order isn't unique this query would fail as it would return multiple values; but maybe that's what you want?

Comment: @xQbert Nothing, but that is not the question …

Comment: Then the answer is somewhat obvious.  Order of operation by the engines is different mySQL must assign the table alias as it's encountered making it available to the rest of the query where as SQLlite engine must assign alias after the values have computed, thus it's not available to the inline select. (when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth)  Thought I don't think we've fully eliminated the impossible yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL standard says that you cannot use a column alias from inside other expressions in the same `SELECT` clause, and SQLite implements this correctly.

To be able to differentiate the two different `tablet_order` values, you have to give at least one of the tables a table alias:

```
SELECT tablet_order AS tablet,
       (SELECT framework_item_id
        FROM framework AS f2
        WHERE f2.tablet_order = framework.tablet_order
       ) AS tablet1
FROM framework
WHERE framework_item_id = 1
```

(The subquery is meaningless because you could just use `framework_item_id` directly. You probably wanted to look up by some other column?)